# How can I create a single Webpack manifest that includes output from multiple configurations?

Tags: webpack

I have a `webpack` configuration which exports two config objects, to generate multiple builds from the same source file for current and legacy browsers. For rendering on the server I'm using `webpack-manifest-plugin` to generate a manifest for each build.

```js
// webpack.config.js
const client = {
  entry: {
    client: './src/client.js',
  },
  //...webpack config for modern browsers
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: '../manifest-client.json',
    }),
  ],
}

const legacy = {
  entry: {
    client: './src/client.js',
  },
  //...webpack config for older browsers
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: '../manifest-legacy.json',
    }),
  ],
}

module.exports = [client, legacy]
```

This works OK, but ideally I'd like to have a single manifest which includes both of these manifests.

Is there a way of achieving this that's simpler than just reading both files when I start the server?

```js
// server.js
const assets = {
  client: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/manifest-client.json')),
  legacy: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/manifest-legacy.json')),
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an article about this exact subject here https://medium.com/@technoblogueur/webpack-one-manifest-json-from-multiple-configurations-output-fee48578eb92

what you need is the **seed** option of WebpackManifestPlugin, you have to pass a shared object to it (in both configurations), here is an example based on your code:

```
// webpack.config.js

var sharedObj = {};

const client = {
  entry: {
    client: './src/client.js',
  },
  //...webpack config for modern browsers
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: '../manifest.json',
      seed: sharedObj
    }),
  ],
}

const legacy = {
  entry: {
    client_lagacy: './src/client_lagacy.js',
  },
  //...webpack config for older browsers
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: '../manifest.json',
      seed: sharedObj
    }),
  ],
}

module.exports = [client, legacy]
```

You need also to be careful in case you are using CleanWebpackPlugin, because the order of bundling is from right to left (talking about the exported array here) so as I mentioned in the post, it should be safe to put CleanWebpackPlugin in the last config.

**Update**

The code snippet above is corrected (As mentioned in the comment) as you are writing to the same manifest, the manifest file name should be the same (manifest.json) but For the entry keys they should be different, you can set one to "client" and the other "client_legacy" so in the manifest json you will have something like:

```
{
  "client_legacy": "client_legacy.[someHash].js",
  "client": "client.[someHash].js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I can't edit your answer but for anyone looking at this example, note that I had to change the `fileName` option to be the same for both entry points, and also rename the legacy entry point to avoid having two `client` keys in the object.

Comment: @velvetkevorkian oh yeah obviously the entry keys should be different (I was so focused on how to write to the same manifest to the point that I haven't noticed you are using the same entry key) because it doesn't make sense to have the same entry output to manifest (the last will override the first) and yes the filename of the manifest should be the same (because you want to write to the same file), I will edit that in the answer

Comment: Does this work with webpack 5? I'm following your examples and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MikePost haven't tried it with Webpack 5 (I moved to Esbuild since v4), things might be changed but I think if you understand the principle you can get it working, check the seed options of manifestPlugin https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin

Comment: Ah, it looks like if you're doing both seed and generate options, you need to mutate the seed value in your generate function. Docs are unclear on that point.

Comment: @MikePost you can maybe post an answer that shows this particular point, I am sure it would help others as well :)